# Multithreaded Recursive task synchronization

Tags: c++, multithreading, recursion

```
void Node::recursiveThing()
{
  for(auto iter = m_children.begin();
  iter != m_children.end();
  iter++)
  {
    s_threadPool->addTask(std::bind(&Node::recursiveThing, (*iter));
  }
}

int main()
{
  Node * hugeThree = makeHugeTreeMethod();
  std::future allIterationsDone = s_threadPool->addTask(std::bind(&Node::recursiveThing, hugeTree));
  allIterationsDone.wait(); // I want to somehow block here until all spawned child tasks are done.
}
```

Yeah.

So my problem is that I'd like to spawn child tasks from a task, which in turn spawn even more child tasks. This works, but how can I know that all spawned child tasks have been completed? Maybe I need to make a thread safe list where they are all appended?

I read somewhere that this might be possible in c++17, but I'd need something now, any ideas?

Comment: What about a vector of futures? You could perhaps iterate through that vector calling `get()` on each element.

Comment: I would just use a waitable counter. Increment it every time you add a task of this type and decrement it every time one completes.

Comment: @Galik But, um, I don't know all of the futures when I make the main task. When a future is completed, it could return more futures and so on. But how do i write this? std::future<std::vector<std::future<std::vector<std::future<std::vector<std::future>>>>>>  and so on..

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Yeah, that's sort of what I had in mind as well.

Comment: @0xbaadf00d Do the tasks return any information? I'm not too great or reading or writing C++ yet, but doing this kind of recursive composition of futures is fairly simple with C#. If I provided an example, do you think you could translate to std::future and C++ delegates?

Comment: IDK, maybe. Tasks can return information. std::future<int> for example returns an integer from a task. Do check my previous comment about this though. A single level of recursion would be doable, but I'm dealing with N levels here.

Comment: @0xbaadf00d Yes, arbitrary number of levels can be supported. Here's the gist of it: http://ideone.com/MDb8Rc. No locking is required.

Comment: @0xbaadf00d I was thinking in terms of passing a `std::vector<std::future<void>>&` down the recursive call stack as a parameter (along with a `std::mutex&` for synchronizing additions). But DavidSchwartz' counter sounds a lot more efficient.

Comment: @0xbaadf00d Are you allowed to use boost? boost futures can be combined into a single future using `boost::when_all`, which very straightforwardly solves your problem.

Comment: @Asad IDK, I must ask my mistress. I might be punished if I'm too deviant. Yes, i will use it. Can you give a very small sample as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hmmm...
yes, C++17 `std::when_all` could have being very helpfull here.

one solution I can think about (psudo code only!):

```
struct TreeTasks
   vector<child*> busyNodes
   mutex vectorLock
   condition_variable vectorCV
   thread taskChecker 

BeforeAll
 lock busyNodes
 add root-node's *this* to busyNodes
 unlock busyNodes
 launch taskChecker with taskChecker Routine

OnNodeTaskFinish
 lock vectorLock
 add child nodes pointers to busyNodes if exist
 remove *this* from busyNodes
 unlock busyNodes
 notify vectorCV

taskChecker Routine
  lock vectorLock
  wait on vectorCV(vectorLock) on predicate -> busyNodes.isEmpty()
  return done
```

this is very similiar on a thread-pool algorithm on how to split the tasks.
we have a vector which containes the node that are being worken on, 
a thread which most of the time just sleeps and wakes up when a size-change occures on the vector.

when a task finishes to work on a node, it may or may not append the children into the vector, but anyway removes itself from it.
the checker thread wakes up - if the vector is empty - all the tasks are done.

Comment: Yes, this gives me an idea, I'll test it later.